# What's the difference between MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'` and MEDIA_ROOT= os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media") in Django setting.py

Tags: django, django-file-upload

I wanted to know the difference between using `MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'` and `MEDIA_ROOT= os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")` in settings.py.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'
```

utilizes **pathlib** library

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
```

utilizes **os** library

The default library depends on which version of Django you employ.

What do you mean by deleting and uploading can you give more detail?

Answer (score 0):

Those are basically the same, but only if `BASE_DIR` is a `pathlib.Path` object.